# How to use hardware decoding of media files using ffmpeg android?

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, stagefright

i am developing a media player application in android which uses ffmpeg for decoding which i think is software decoding. it doesn't play high resolution videos smoothly so i would like to switch to hardware decoding. I came to know that libstagefright will do the thing. But how to implement it using libstagefright? Is there any samples or documentation . Please help in using the libstagefright.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using ICS you can use MediaCodec to encode or decode using hardware.
see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html for more details and examples.
Thanks,
NinjAndroid,
MoMinis R&D team

Comment: I am developing for android 3.2+. Is there any docs regarding libstagefright?

Comment: Using the default mediaplayer and other classes should use the stagefright libraries.